# $C^0$ norm is bounded by $L^{14}$ norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed manifold of dimension $6$, and we look at the collection of smooth functions on $M$ which satisfy:
$$
\|f\|_{C^0}\leq C\big(\|f\|_{L^{14}}^2+1\big)
$$
for some fixed $C>0$. Can we get some uniform bound on $f$ (some $L^p$ bound or $C^0$ bound) using this? What else can be said about $f$?

Comment: Not clear: if f is a large enough constant the inequality is certainly true...